# Cypher/Neo4j: How to match nodes related to n "consecutive" nodes

Tags: date, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to match listing availabilities in my graph (Airbnb-like).

- The graph has 1 node per date, and consecutive days are linked by a NEXT_DAY edge.
- Listings are linked to day nodes by an AVAILABLE edge (if they are available)

I'm trying to write a query which returns all listings which are available from start_date to end_date.

I know the following FOREACH syntax is incorrect but I may help giving the general idea:

```
MATCH period=(a)-[:NEXT_DAY*]->(c)
WHERE a.date="2013-01-20" AND c.date="2013-01-24"

MATCH (listing:Listing)-[:AVAILABLE]->(d:Date)
FOREACH (d IN nodes(period))

RETURN listing
```

*Bonus question: How could I proceed if I wanted to score listings proportionally to their availability match with the query (e.g. 100% if the listing is available during the whole period, 50% if it is only available half of the period) ?*

Thanks in advance :)

Benjamin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UNWIND` to get get the nodes from your date path and `MATCH` them to `Listing`.

```
MATCH period=(a)-[:NEXT_DAY*]->(c)
WHERE a.date="2013-01-20" AND c.date="2013-01-24"

// UNWIND gets a collection of ndoes and transforms them to single/matchable nodes
UNWIND nodes(period) as nodes_in_period
MATCH (nodes_in_period)<-[:AVAILABLE]-(listing:Listing)

RETURN listing
```

And for the bonus question: If I get it right, you can count the number of `AVAILABLE` relationships from `Listing` to `Date` and compare it to the number of `Date` nodes in your period. `OPTIONAL MATCH` might help:

```
MATCH period=(a)-[:NEXT_DAY*]->(c)
WHERE a.date="2013-01-20" AND c.date="2013-01-24"
UNWIND nodes(period) as nodes_in_period

OPTIONAL MATCH (nodes_in_period)<-[a:AVAILABLE]-(listing:Listing)

// return the listing, the number of available relationships 
// and the number of days in period
RETURN listing, count(a), count(nodes_in_period)
```

Comment: Beautiful ! Thank you :)
In terms of efficiency how does UNWIND differ from:
MATCH (l:Listing)-[r:AVAILABLE]->(d)
WHERE d IN nodes(period)

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen, you are insanely fast in creating neo4j consoles

Comment: @bpipat, not sure what is faster, I think you have to test it. I would guess UNWIND though.

Comment: @MartinPreusse graphgen FTW

Comment: @MartinPreusse some quick testing shows UNWIND is about 30 times more efficient :)